# Circular file dependency dropped weirdness

Tags: gnu-make

I'm running a little utility from a make file (using GNU Make 3.81). The utility converts one type of file to another. For example the file '**thefile.x**' gets converted to '**thefile.x.y**'.

The target and make rule is:

```
%.x.y: %.x
    convertfile $< $@

all: file1.x.y file2.x.y
```

This actually works (the .x.y file is produced but I always get the message:

**make: Circular thefile.x <- thefile.x.y dependency dropped.**

This is just a minor issue as we don't want to see messages when everything is actually working.

Have looked at other 'circular dependency' Q&As and none of them seem to be the same problem I'm having. For other technical reasons I can't change the file naming conventions for this project.

After comment below I want to clarify what I'm doing and so reproduce the complete make file I'm using:

```
%.js.c: %.js
    js2c $< $@

all: test1.js.c test2.js.c
```

Here is output when I run it and it has stuff to do:

```
C:\work\timtest>make
make: Circular test1.js <- test1.js.c dependency dropped.
js2c test1.js test1.js.c
[RomFs] test1.js => test1.js.c
make: Circular test2.js <- test2.js.c dependency dropped.
js2c test2.js test2.js.c
[RomFs] test2.js => test2.js.c
```

Here is output when nothing to do:

```
make: Circular test1.js <- test1.js.c dependency dropped.
make: Circular test2.js <- test2.js.c dependency dropped.
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Comment: That is not a fully-formed makefile that shows the problem you're having.  When I use this makefile and run `touch file1.x`, I don't see that warning.

Comment: See additional stuff in main question...

Comment: Thanks.  Now that your example uses the actual suffixes, the problem is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this because GNU make has a number of [built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html).  You can see a partial listing of them in the GNU make manual, or run `make -p -f/dev/null` to see a complete list.

One of these built-in rules tells make how to compile a program from a `.c` file.  On POSIX systems programs don't have special suffixes, so this built-in rule says, basically:

```
%: %.c ; $(LINK.c) ...
```

So this rule tells make how to build any file `foo` from a file `foo.c`... this also means make can infer how to build a file `foo.js` from a file `foo.js.c`.  Since you've also defined a rule for how to build `foo.js.c` from `foo.js`, that's a circular dependency and make evicts one of the rules (the built-in rule).

You need to prevent your `.js` files from being matched via [match-anything patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html) like the one above.  There are two ways to do this as described in the manual.  The one with the least side-effects is to add an empty pattern rule mentioning your new suffix, like this:

```
%.js:
```

That's it.  Full details are available in the manual.

Comment: Fantastic, I never thought of the inbuilt rules! Thanks